# Текстовый редактор Kate в Fedora. Показывать поверх других окон при загрузке нескольких файлов.файла

Tags: linux, fedora

Имеется Fedora 36, файл-менеджер Krusader и текстовый редактор Kate.
При еще не запущенном редакторе Kate и нажатии клавиши F4 в Krusader на файле происходит открытие Kate и загрузка файла в редактор.
Если, не закрывая Kate, хочется открыть еще один файл на редактирование, то файл в Kate загрузится, но окно Kate остается скрытым за другими окнами.
Вопрос: можно ли сделать что-то, что позволяло бы показавать окно текстового редактора Kate при загрузке в него второго и последующих файлов поверх остальных окон? Наподобие Notepad++ в Windows.
Или другой тестовый редактор. Пробовал Sublime, но там поведение то же самое.